# Getting error when trying to get Transaction Events Logs

Tags: solidity, blockchain, hardhat, ethereumjs

I am trying to check whether an event is emitted or not in my unit test.
But getting error as length undefined.

The error I am getting is

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/Institution-test.js:84:21)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Here is my Institution.sol Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.14;

import "./Certification.sol";

error NotOwner();

contract Institution {
    // State Variables
    address public owner;

    // Mappings
    mapping(address => Institute) private institutes; // Institutes Mapping
    mapping(address => Course[]) private instituteCourses; // Courses Mapping

    // Events
    event instituteAdded(string indexed _instituteName);

    // Modifier
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != owner) revert NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    struct Course {
        string course_name;
        string course_code;
        // Other attributes can be added
    }

    struct Institute {
        string institute_name;
        string institute_acronym;
        string institute_link;
    }

    function stringToBytes32(
        string memory source
    ) private pure returns (bytes32 result) {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringTest = bytes(source);
        if (tempEmptyStringTest.length == 0) {
            return 0x0;
        }
        assembly {
            result := mload(add(source, 32))
        }
    }

    function addInstitute(
        address _address,
        string memory _institute_name,
        string memory _institute_acronym,
        string memory _institute_link,
        Course[] memory _institute_courses
    ) public onlyOwner {
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(
            institutes[_address].institute_name
        );
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length == 0,
            "Institute with token already exists"
        );
        require(
            _institute_courses.length > 0,
            "Atleast one course must be added"
        );
        institutes[_address] = Institute(
            _institute_name,
            _institute_acronym,
            _institute_link
        );
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _institute_courses.length; i++) {
            instituteCourses[_address].push(_institute_courses[i]);
        }

        emit instituteAdded(_institute_name);
    }

    // Called by Institutions
    function getInstituteData()
        public
        view
        returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    {
        Institute memory temp = institutes[msg.sender];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
            "Institute account does not exist!"
        );
        return (
            temp.institute_name,
            temp.institute_acronym,
            temp.institute_link,
            instituteCourses[msg.sender]
        );
    }

    // Called by Smart Contracts
    function getInstituteData(
        address _address
    )
        public
        view
        returns (string memory, string memory, string memory, Course[] memory)
    {
        require(
            Certification(msg.sender).owner() == owner,
            "Incorrect smart contract & authorizations!"
        );
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        require(
            tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0,
            "Institute does not exist!"
        );
        return (
            temp.institute_name,
            temp.institute_acronym,
            temp.institute_link,
            instituteCourses[_address]
        );
    }

    function checkInstitutePermission(
        address _address
    ) public view returns (bool) {
        Institute memory temp = institutes[_address];
        bytes memory tempEmptyStringNameTest = bytes(temp.institute_name);
        if (tempEmptyStringNameTest.length > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Institution-test.js

```js
const web3 = require("web3");
const { assert, expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Institution Contract", function () {
  let mockOwner_acc,
    mockInstitute_acc,
    mockInvalid_acc,
    mockInstitute,
    mockInstitute_course,
    institution;

  beforeEach(async function () {
    const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();
    mockOwner_acc = accounts[0];
    mockInstitute_acc = accounts[1];
    mockInvalid_acc = accounts[2];

    mockInstitute = {
      institute_name: "Heritage Institute of Technology",
      institute_acronym: "HITK",
      institute_link: "www.heritageit.edu",
    };

    mockInstitute_course = [
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Engineering",
        course_code: "CSE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Electronics and Communication Engineering",
        course_code: "ECE",
      },
      {
        course_name: "Computer Science and Business Studies",
        course_code: "CSBS",
      },
    ];

    const Institution = await ethers.getContractFactory("Institution");
    institution = await Institution.deploy({
      from: mockOwner_acc,
    });
  });

  describe("Deployment of Institution Contract", () => {
    it("It has correct owner", async function () {
      const instituteContract_owner = await institution.owner();
      assert.equal(instituteContract_owner, mockOwner_acc.address);
    });
  });

  describe("Adding institute", () => {
    it("Only owner can add Institute, others cannot add", async function () {
      const attackerConnectedAccounts = await institution.connect(
        mockInvalid_acc
      );
      await expect(
        attackerConnectedAccounts.addInstitute(
          mockInstitute_acc.address,
          mockInstitute.institute_name,
          mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
          mockInstitute.institute_link,
          mockInstitute_course
        )
      ).to.be.revertedWithCustomError(attackerConnectedAccounts, "NotOwner");
    });

    it("Adds an institute with valid details", async function () {
      const receipt = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstitute_course,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

      console.log(receipt);

      assert.equal(receipt.logs.length, 1);
      assert.equal(receipt.logs[0].event, "instituteAdded");
      assert.equal(
        receipt.logs[0].args._institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_name
      );
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that you are mocking a `Contract` with `ethers` (ethers.js), you'd need to write the `addInstitution` call differently:

```js
const tx = await institution.addInstitute(
        mockInstitute_acc.address,
        mockInstitute.institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_acronym,
        mockInstitute.institute_link,
        mockInstitute_course,
        { from: mockOwner_acc }
      );

const { events, logs } = await tx.wait();

// Example tx.wait() return...
// {
//   blockHash: '0x9340a9c7efafbb4ad9a6ebda62e3311ec5fc40ddcc733632938a988c8c62b885',
//   blockNumber: 60330,
//   byzantium: true,
//   confirmations: 1,
//   contractAddress: null,
//   cumulativeGasUsed: { BigNumber: "51558" },
//   effectiveGasPrice: { BigNumber: "1500000007" },
//   events: [
//     {
//       address: '0x70ff5c5B1Ad0533eAA5489e0D5Ea01485d530674',
//       args: [
//         '0x46E0726Ef145d92DEA66D38797CF51901701926e',
//         '0x5555763613a12D8F3e73be831DFf8598089d3dCa',
//         { BigNumber: "1230000000000000000" },
//         amount: { BigNumber: "1230000000000000000" },
//         from: '0x46E0726Ef145d92DEA66D38797CF51901701926e',
//         to: '0x5555763613a12D8F3e73be831DFf8598089d3dCa'
//       ],
//       blockHash: '0x9340a9c7efafbb4ad9a6ebda62e3311ec5fc40ddcc733632938a988c8c62b885',
//       blockNumber: 60330,
//       data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111d67bb1bb0000',
//       decode: [Function (anonymous)],
//       event: 'Transfer',
//       eventSignature: 'Transfer(address,address,uint256)',
//       getBlock: [Function (anonymous)],
//       getTransaction: [Function (anonymous)],
//       getTransactionReceipt: [Function (anonymous)],
//       logIndex: 0,
//       removeListener: [Function (anonymous)],
//       topics: [
//         '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
//         '0x00000000000000000000000046e0726ef145d92dea66d38797cf51901701926e',
//         '0x0000000000000000000000005555763613a12d8f3e73be831dff8598089d3dca'
//       ],
//       transactionHash: '0xafdc1f7ec14e2e05a39826c134c9157e0011fc784aef623df3fdf9b9d29f3ac8',
//       transactionIndex: 0
//     }
//   ],
//   from: '0x46E0726Ef145d92DEA66D38797CF51901701926e',
//   gasUsed: { BigNumber: "51558" },
//   logs: [
//     {
//       address: '0x70ff5c5B1Ad0533eAA5489e0D5Ea01485d530674',
//       blockHash: '0x9340a9c7efafbb4ad9a6ebda62e3311ec5fc40ddcc733632938a988c8c62b885',
//       blockNumber: 60330,
//       data: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111d67bb1bb0000',
//       logIndex: 0,
//       topics: [
//         '0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef',
//         '0x00000000000000000000000046e0726ef145d92dea66d38797cf51901701926e',
//         '0x0000000000000000000000005555763613a12d8f3e73be831dff8598089d3dca'
//       ],
//       transactionHash: '0xafdc1f7ec14e2e05a39826c134c9157e0011fc784aef623df3fdf9b9d29f3ac8',
//       transactionIndex: 0
//     }
//   ],
//   logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000800000000000004000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000008000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000008000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000',
//   status: 1,
//   to: '0x70ff5c5B1Ad0533eAA5489e0D5Ea01485d530674',
//   transactionHash: '0xafdc1f7ec14e2e05a39826c134c9157e0011fc784aef623df3fdf9b9d29f3ac8',
//   transactionIndex: 0,
//   type: 2
// }
```

---

*And to work-around failing transaction tests, you could do something like that to prevent an error in your test file:*

```js
    it("Adds an institute with valid details", async function () {
      // ...
      if (logs.length < 1) {
        assert.equal(
            false,
            true,
            'No events emitted, receipt log`s length is < 1'
        );
      }

      assert.equal(logs.length, 1);
      assert.equal(logs[0].event, "instituteAdded");
      assert.equal(
        receipt.logs[0].args._institute_name,
        mockInstitute.institute_name
      );
    });
```

---

(For reference: https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/example/)

Comment: The above one works but in test file I have to do
```javascript
assert.equal(logs.length, 1);
assert.equal(logs[0].fragment.name, "instituteAdded");
assert.equal(logs[0].args._instituteName, mockInstitute.institute_name);
```